# Express JS - using params to retrieve info from database but when refreshing page it crashes

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, parameters

I have been trying to solve this but I really got stuck. I'm still learning web development so I'm really lost on why this is happening and how to solve it.
There is a mysql table called *ticket* and I want to get all its information to display it in a page. I'm using express and react.

I'm using nodemon and it shows the following error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot remove headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at ServerResponse.removeHeader (node:_http_outgoing:711:11)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\millenas\Documents\cxbunal\api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:214:10)  
    at file:///C:/Users/millenas/Documents/cxbunal/api/UserRoutes.js:19:28  
    at C:\Users\millenas\Documents\cxbunal\api\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:223:12
    at getSecret (C:\Users\millenas\Documents\cxbunal\api\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:90:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (C:\Users\millenas\Documents\cxbunal\api\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:94:10)
    at file:///C:/Users/millenas/Documents/cxbunal/api/UserRoutes.js:10:18  
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\millenas\Documents\cxbunal\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\millenas\Documents\cxbunal\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot remove headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at ServerResponse.removeHeader (node:_http_outgoing:711:11)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\millenas\Documents\cxbunal\api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:214:10)  
    at file:///C:/Users/millenas/Documents/cxbunal/api/UserRoutes.js:19:28  
    at C:\Users\millenas\Documents\cxbunal\api\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:223:12
    at getSecret (C:\Users\millenas\Documents\cxbunal\api\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:90:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (C:\Users\millenas\Documents\cxbunal\api\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:94:10)
    at file:///C:/Users/millenas/Documents/cxbunal/api/UserRoutes.js:10:18  
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\millenas\Documents\cxbunal\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\millenas\Documents\cxbunal\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
node:internal/errors:477
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);      
    ^
listening on port: 3030
node:internal/errors:477
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the    at file:///C:/Users/millenas/Documents/cxbunal/api/TicketRoutes.js:39:26    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {   code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'       
}[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

UserRoutes.js:

```js
import express from 'express';
import jsonwebtoken from 'jsonwebtoken';
import db from "./db.js";

const UserRoutes = express.Router();
const secret = 'hardcoded123';

UserRoutes.get('/profile', ((req, res) => {
    const token = req.cookies.token;
    jsonwebtoken.verify(token, secret, (err, data) => {
        if(err){
            res.status(403).send();
        }
        else {

            res.json(data).send();
        }
    });
}));


UserRoutes.post('/login', ((req,res) => {
    const {email, password} = req.body;

    db.select('password')
    .where({email})
    .from('users')
    .first()
    .then(user => {
          const isLoginOk = password === user.password;

          isLoginOk && jsonwebtoken.sign(email, secret, (err, token) => {
              if (err) {
                res.status(403).send(); //forbidden - access denied
              }
              else {
                db('users').where({email}).update({token})
                    .then(() => res.cookie('token', token).send('ok'))
                    .catch(() => res.sendStatus(422));
                }
          });
    
          if (!isLoginOk) {
              res.status(403).send('Incorrect email or password.');
          }
      })
      .catch(e => {
        res.status(422).send('Oops. Something went wrong.');
        console.log(e);
      });    
}));

UserRoutes.post('/logout', ((req, res) => {
    res.clearCookie('token').send('ok');
}));

export default UserRoutes;
```

TicketRoutes.js:

```js
import express from 'express';
import db from './db.js';

const TicketRoutes = express.Router();

TicketRoutes.post('/tickets', (req,res) => {
    const {title, content, priority} = req.body;
    const {token} = req.cookies;
    db.select('id').from('users').where({token}).first().then(user => {
        if(user && user.id) {
            db('tickets').insert({
                title,
                content,
                priority,
                parent_id: null,
                author_id: user.id,
                status: 'open',
            }).then(() => {
                res.sendStatus(201);
            }).catch(() => res.sendStatus(422));
        }
        else {
            res.sendStatus(403);
        }
    });

});


TicketRoutes.get('/tickets/:id', (req,res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    db.select('*')
        .from('tickets')
        .where({id})
        .first()
        .then(ticket => {
            res.json(ticket).send();
        })
        .catch(() => res.sendStatus(422)); 
});

export default TicketRoutes;
```

TicketPage.js:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import gfm from 'remark-gfm';
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';

const Container = styled.div`
    padding: 30px 20px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 40px 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
`;


const HeaderRow = styled.div`
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr min-content min-content min-content;
    grid-column-gap: 15px;
`;

const StyledHeader = styled.h1`
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #032c5b;


`;
const Tag = styled.span`
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 3px;
  background-color: #4c4d50;
  color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
`;

const Labels = styled.h3`
    color: #032c5b;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-top: 10px;
   
`;

const TicketBody = styled.div`
  color: #032c5b;
  border: 2px solid #032c5b;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 15px;
`

function TicketPage() {

  const [ticket, setTicket] = useState(false);
  const params = useParams();



  useEffect(() => {
    function fetchTicket(){
      axios.get('http://localhost:3030/tickets/'+params.id)
           .then(response => {
              setTicket(response.data.ticket);
           });
    };
  
  fetchTicket()
  }, [params.id]);


  return (
    <>
    <Container>
      {ticket && (
      <><HeaderRow>
            <StyledHeader>{ticket && ticket.title}</StyledHeader>
            <Labels>22/02/2022</Labels>
            <Labels>Closed</Labels>
            <Labels>High</Labels>
          </HeaderRow>
          <Labels>by Millena Freitas</Labels>
          <TicketBody>
              <ReactMarkdown plugins={[gfm]} children={ticket.content} />
            </TicketBody>
        </>
        
      )}
        

    </Container>
    </>
  );
}

export default TicketPage
```

If you need to see anything more please ask. Thank you so much for anyone willing to help me :)

Comment: The double request is not relevant to the problem you described in the rest of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `.send()` from `res.json(data).send()`.

I'm able to see the issue from the stack trace.

## Canonical stack trace troubleshooting steps

Given a stack trace,

```
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at ServerResponse.removeHeader (node:_http_outgoing:711:11)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\millenas\Documents\cxbunal\api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:214:10)  
    at file:///C:/Users/millenas/Documents/cxbunal/api/UserRoutes.js:19:28  
    at C:\Users\millenas\Documents\cxbunal\api\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:223:12
```

Going from the bottom up,

- **[`verify.js:223`](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/blob/74d5719bd03993fcf71e3b176621f133eb6138c0/verify.js#L223)**: `return done(null, payload)` shows that the verify function completed without error.
- **`api/UserRoutes.js`** gives us the code for the callback. Line 19 doesn't match up with anything significant (probably because the code has changed since the error was shown), but gives us the route. We can see there is conditional logic based on whether there was an error or not. We know there is no error. That leaves us with only one line to look at

So the problematic line is:

```
        res.json(data).send();
```

Looking up the [documentation for `res.json()`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json), we can see it is not chainable. Remove `.send()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did it and it removed those erros but now it showed new errors. I tried to look up the same way you did but they dont seem as clear.

Comment: `node:internal/errors:477
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);      
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:603:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\millenas\Documents\cxbunal\api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {   code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'       }[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`

Comment: Thank you so much!! You really helped me. I have been trying for hours... After most of the errors were fixed with your help, I did a little research and then everything with res I added return and also changed all the res.sendStatus to res.status(statuscode).send() and now everything works!!!